# C# SQL WHERE DateTime Today

Tags: sql-server, datetime, ms-access

I have a database table in Access that looks like this:

[image: database]

I have a problem with my SQL, I want a 2 `WHERE`'s in my SQL Statement which I have tried, and it looks like this in server explorer

```
SELECT Created, [Action], 
       ConnectionLoc, 
       ConnectionSystem, 
       Resource, 
       [Text], 
       RecordId, 
       ToVal, 
       ClientName    
  FROM tblAudit
 WHERE (ClientName = '*Variable*') AND 
       ('WHERE Created'  = '[DateTime].Today')
```

I want only the records with today's date to show.... Hence this bit. Yet nothing is returned. I know the first `WHERE` is correct since on its own it outputs fine. It's the second one which is wrong.

Comment: Since you tagged with `C#`, I assume you try to run this sql with it, you can use a parameterized query and pass this `DateTime.Today` value directly.

Comment: Maybe this is irrelevant, but why are you using `[columnName]` around some columns, and some without? I would suggest doing `[columnName]` everywhere, or nowhere.

Also I would advice selecting the `schema` before the `database` like this `[dbo].[tblAudit]`

Comment: jp Houten i probably should but i am new to programming  and i do not know the conventions yet as i have no real life experience..

Comment: What are you using to connect to the database?

Comment: I'm using a connector class given to me by my teacher...

Comment: What's the name of the class?

Comment: Are you using ADO.Net or something else?

Comment: I have no idea...how do I find out.

Comment: Probably look inside `clsDBConnector.cs`. And look for a connection string. It'll probably say Jet or ACE.

Comment: it uses ACE from what i can see

Comment: If you just want to hardcode the query it will look like this: `WHERE ClientName = '*Variable*' AND Created'  = #12/22/2015#` I'm pretty sure that's the right format for date literals but you might want to second guess me.

Comment: no errors for that but still no data is showing...  but even the way i did it originally had no errors, just nothing shows up

Comment: I think I have what's wrong

Comment: in the database it saves it like this 22/12/2015 because its made to auto update the date and time in the database but the program is looking for 12/22/2015

Comment: The reason your first attempt returned no rows was because you were comparing two unequal strings inside the single quotes. Yes, the date format would depend on which country you're from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hating to answer my own question... Firstly thanks to

- *Kevin Brechbühl*

  and
- *shawnt00*

the problem was the date format, in my access database it was *dd/MM/yyyy* but visual studio was looking for *mm/DD/yyyy* hence the errors

Answer (score 2):

```
  WHERE ClientName = 'Variable' AND cast( Created as date) = cast(getdate() as date)
```

Try this. Where clause is required only once

Answer (score 1):

Try this using [`GETDATE()`](http://www.w3schools.com/Sql/func_getdate.asp) function:

```
SELECT
    Created,
    [Action],
    ConnectionLoc,
    ConnectionSystem,
    [Resource],
    [Text],
    RecordId,
    ToVal,
    ClientName
FROM tblAudit
WHERE ClientName = 'Variable'
    AND CAST(Created AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

Comment: cast(Created as date) = cast(getdate() as date) i do not get this part.. im sorry i am still a faily new programmer, i tried using a function to return the date but i dont know how to make it work with your code. the function is called ToDate(); and is a DateTime.

Comment: @ArthurVerrept getdate() is a function from SQL server, so you only need to replace your complete query with mine and it should work.

Comment: And what is the error message? What happens when you execute this directly on the SQL server?

Comment: @ArthurVerrept The query you execute is not the query which was suggested ;-) You've tried with `ToDate()`, my answer says `GETDATE()`.

Comment: just tried and yeah my bad... but still error https://gyazo.com/db49693852c86dc68ee56250c3a267a2

Comment: What happens when you try `Date()` instead of `GetDate()`?

Comment: still errors... i tried just date() this pops up first https://gyazo.com/1cdff7489ab57e8fd77d1e605da81189

Comment: Depending on your `Created` field, maybe you don't need to cast the dates and this will also work: `AND Created = DATE()`

Answer (score 0):

For a query against an Access table you can use

```sql
... WHERE ... AND [Created]=Date()
```

if the [Created] column contains just date values (without a time component).

Note also that `[ClientName] = '*sometext*'` will perform a *literal* search, not a *wildcard* search. To do a wildcard search from C# you need to use `[ClientName] LIKE '%sometext%'`.

Comment: Does wildcard mean that it searches for the closest word? because everything is handled from the database and no writing is needed a literal search should be fine.... thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

As this is Access, you can do:

```
FROM 
    tblAudit
WHERE 
    (ClientName Like '*Variable*') AND (Created = Date())
```

Answer (score 0):

This is so simple. if you have column on database that named "date" this code works.
this using mysql server.

```
private void getdatawheredatenow()
{
MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection(con);
connect.Open();
try
{
string sql="SELECT * FROM DATE WHERE date(date) = date(now())";
MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, connect);
DataTable ds = new DataTable();
da.Fill(ds);
datagrid.Datasource = ds;
}
catch(Exception aa)
{
Console.WriteLine(aa.ToString());
}
}
```

Comment: You might want to change your example to use a column name (`date`) which is not  a function name.

Comment: no. the column name is before (date). "SELECT * FROM DATE WHERE expireddate(date) = date(now())";